# How to learn Group Theory and Algebra from a Category Theory background?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

I've been studying category theory using [Applied Category Theory](https://www.appliedcategorytheory.org/), which well explains all the core concepts even for people without much mathematical background.

Since one of the appeals of CT is that a bunch of math is a special case of some Category Theoretical concept, I was wondering if there was a resource to study Algebra / Group Theory (which I have ~0 background in, except by absorbing them from examples in the ACT textbook) from a Category Theoretical perspective, i.e. explicitly pointing out the connections.

Most textbooks I've seen didn't invoke CT all that much, so I had to find those connections myself or look them up. Any recommendations?

Comment: Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0" is a very pleasant read, and seems to fit your criteria well.

Comment: @AlexWertheim: You should consider posting it as an answer, as it is *the* answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it definitely seems like what I'm looking for! I'd accept it if posted as an answer. By any chance, does it also include Group Theory?

Comment: "A course in Homological Algebra" by Stammbach & Hilton might also be a good fit besides "chapter 0"